# how to understand const and pointer in C++ expression below?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, declaration

I am reading application code developed in the IBM [RSARTE](https://rsarte.hcldoc.com/help/topic/com.ibm.xtools.rsarte.webdoc/users-guide/overview.html) C++ version. Here is a piece of C++ code:

```
const char * const * av = RTMain::argStrings();
```

How to understand the left-hand side syntax when there are two `const` and two `*`?

Comment: I usually prefer right const which makes types like these easier to decipher, since a const applies to everything on the left. `char const* const*` would be the right const version for the type of `av`. You could define type aliases here though to make this more clear `using A = char const*; using B = A const*; B av = ...;`: You've got a pointer to a pointer to a char; Neither the char itself nor the pointer to it can be modified, but you could assign assign a different pointer to `av` itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const char * const * av = RTMain::argStrings();
```

is the same as

```
char const * const * av = RTMain::argStrings();
```

`const` applies to what's left of `const`.

So, `av` is a non-`const` pointer to a `const*` to `const char`.

- The returned pointer, `av`, is non-`const` and can be changed.
- The pointer `av` is pointing at is `const` and can not be changed.
- The `char` that pointer is pointing at is `const` and can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Read this declaration

```
const char * const * av
```

from right to left. There is declared the pointer `av` ( `* av` ) that points to a constant pointer ( `* const` ) that in turn points to an object of the type `const char`.

To simplify this declaration consider this code snippet.

```
const char *literal = "Hello World!";
const char * const * pointer_to_the pointer_literal = &literal;
```

So using the pointer `pointer_to_the pointer_literal` you may not write for example

```
*pointer_to_the pointer_literal = "Bye";
```

and you may not write

```
**pointer_to_the pointer_literal = 'h';
```